# Does it converge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin^n\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does it converge? $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin^n\frac{1}{n}$

I'm trying to solve it with the ratio test and using L'hopital, but it does not seem to go well. Can anyone help please?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\sin(y)} = 1$ therefore $(\arcsin(1/n))^n \sim 1/n^n$

Comment: The sum is approximately $1.888630313853552316$, if anyone is curious. No apparent closed form by Mathematica or ISC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the root test, we have 
$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(|a_n|)^\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\arcsin(\tfrac{1}{n})|=0<1,
$$
so the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

It converges drastically.

Since,
for $0 \le x \le \pi/2$
we have
$1 \ge \dfrac{\sin x}{x}
\ge \dfrac{2}{\pi}
$,
so that
$1 \ge \dfrac{ x}{\arcsin x}
\ge \dfrac{2}{\pi}
$.

Therefore
$1 
\le \dfrac{\arcsin x}{ x}
\le \dfrac{\pi}{2}
$,
so
$\arcsin x
\le \dfrac{\pi x}{2}
$.

In particular,
$\arcsin \dfrac1{n}
\le \dfrac{\pi }{2n}
$.

Therefore
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin^{1+c}\dfrac{1}{n}
$
converges for any
$c > 1$
by comparison with
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{1+c}}
$.

Note that
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} \arcsin\dfrac{1}{n}
$
diverges since
$\arcsin\dfrac{1}{n}
\ge \dfrac1{n}
$.